# CSS3 Gradient just repeating thin lines a bunch of times

Tags: css, gradient

I'm trying to make a gradient background for my website, http://www.lathamcity.com

The problem is, as you can see, it just repeats the blue and cyan a bunch of times instead of making a gradient out of them.

To add to the mystery, when two links are clicked on to open a third div, the gradient suddenly changes.  The third div extends below the second one, and the distance between them is occupied by the first gradient color and the rest up to the top of the page is just a normal gradient.

Here's the code I'm using for the gradients.

```
body{
background-color: #1B0D70;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(214,231,232) 49%, rgb(36,155,171) 75%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(214,231,232) 49%, rgb(36,155,171) 75%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(214,231,232) 49%, rgb(36,155,171) 75%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(214,231,232) 49%, rgb(36,155,171) 75%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(214,231,232) 49%, rgb(36,155,171) 75%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0.49, rgb(214,231,232)),
color-stop(0.75, rgb(36,155,171))
);
}
```

Comment: Glad you got your answer however I would like to chip in that you are suing tables for your layout on your page. This is a really outdated way of mark up, an is really bad for accessibility. If you have time try and take a look out using divs for layout article explaining why http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it for sure!

Comment: Cool it will save you time in the long run good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your `body height` is `0px` because your most of the element are `absolute position`.

Write  this in your css:

```
html, body{
 height:100%;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick!  So what exactly was wrong with this and how did the problem come about?

Comment: body contain inner content height like DIV etc. So, if there no content or element are absolute like in your example. Then the default height of the body is 0px